# An UPDATE runs unexpectedly on MySQL 5.7 whereas it runs as expected on prior versions

Tags: mysql, update, query

I use a column called `sequence` on tables where I have to re-sort blocks of rows into an arbitrarily order.

```
CREATE TABLE `tkmemberstage` (
  `ID` bigint(22) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tkmembershipID` bigint(22) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sequence` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `tkmembershipID` (`tkmembershipID`)
)

insert into tkmemberstage set tkmembershipID = 1, sequence = 10;
insert into tkmemberstage set tkmembershipID = 1, sequence = 20;
insert into tkmemberstage set tkmembershipID = 1, sequence = 30;
insert into tkmemberstage set tkmembershipID = 1, sequence = 40;
```

A few years back I researched the following as a means of resequencing a block of rows in a single `UPDATE`

This works by creating an interim virtual table and then updating the entire block of rows in one transaction instead of having to write each row out programmatically.

The `UPDATE` statement goes like this:

```
update 
tkmemberstage 
join 
(select tkmemberstage.ID,
(@newSequence := @newSequence+10) as newSequence 
from 
tkmemberstage 
cross join 
(select @newSequence := 0) 
constructedTable 
where 
tkmemberstage.tkmembershipID = 1  
order by tkmemberstage.sequence) 
constructedTableReordered 
on tkmemberstage.ID=constructedTableReordered.ID 
set tkmemberstage.sequence=constructedTableReordered.newSequence;
```

I have copied it verbatim from a development server in order not to add any translation problems to the mix.

I currently have this running on a mix of RDS servers in the AWS cloud and on anything other than a 5.7 server it works as expected.

In troubleshooting this I tried to deconstruct the statement and try it in partial chunks.

Here is the dataset I'm working on:

```
mysql> select ID, sequence from tkmemberstage;
+----+----------+
| ID | sequence |
+----+----------+
|  1 |       10 |
|  2 |       20 |
|  3 |       30 |
|  4 |       40 |
+----+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I then perform an update to sequence on a single row:

```
mysql> update tkmemberstage set sequence=sequence - 11 where tkmemberstage.ID = 4;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select ID, sequence from tkmemberstage;
+----+----------+
| ID | sequence |
+----+----------+
|  1 |       10 |
|  2 |       20 |
|  3 |       30 |
|  4 |       29 |
+----+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now if I run the `SELECT` part of the `UPDATE` statement I get exactly what we expect:

```
mysql> select tkmemberstage.ID,(@newSequence := @newSequence+10) as newSequence from tkmemberstage cross join (select @newSequence := 0) constructedTable where tkmemberstage.tkmembershipID = 1  order by tkmemberstage.sequence;
+----+-------------+
| ID | newSequence |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |          10 |
|  2 |          20 |
|  4 |          30 |
|  3 |          40 |
+----+-------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And yet when I run the final UPDATE statement itself here is the result:

```
mysql> update tkmemberstage join (select tkmemberstage.ID,(@newSequence := @newSequence+10) as newSequence from tkmemberstage cross join (select @newSequence := 0) constructedTable where tkmemberstage.tkmembershipID = 1  order by tkmemberstage.sequence) constructedTableReordered on tkmemberstage.ID=constructedTableReordered.ID set tkmemberstage.sequence=constructedTableReordered.newSequence;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> select ID, sequence from tkmemberstage;
+----+----------+
| ID | sequence |
+----+----------+
|  1 |       10 |
|  2 |       20 |
|  3 |       30 |
|  4 |       40 |
+----+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So the first obvious question is what changed in 5.7 that could/would cause this kind of behaviour.

*(It's been consistent for well over 6 months now. I just patched the 5.7 server today and retested and still the same results. I also installed 5.7 on a AWS AMI (Cloud9) instance where I did these tests so this behaviour is now confirmed on numerous instances of 5.7.)*

The second question is of course what exactly do we do about it?

The third, a nice to know, is how would we go deeper in troubleshooting this?

For what it is worth here is the `EXPLAIN` of the `UPDATE` on 5.7:

```
mysql> explain update tkmemberstage join (select tkmemberstage.ID,(@newSequence := @newSequence+10) as newSequence from tkmemberstage cross join (select @newSequence := 0) constructedTable where tkmemberstage.tkmembershipID = 1  order by tkmemberstage.sequence) constructedTableReordered on tkmemberstage.ID=constructedTableReordered.ID set tkmemberstage.sequence=constructedTableReordered.newSequence;                                                                                                                                                                                                          
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table         | partitions | type | possible_keys  | key         | key_len | ref                           | rows | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | UPDATE      | tkmemberstage | NULL       | ALL  | PRIMARY        | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                          |    4 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>    | NULL       | ref  | <auto_key0>    | <auto_key0> | 8       | well20180515.tkmemberstage.ID |    2 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tkmemberstage | NULL       | ALL  | tkmembershipID | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                          |    4 |   100.00 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3>    | NULL       | ALL  | NULL           | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                          |    1 |   100.00 | Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)        |
|  3 | DERIVED     | NULL          | NULL       | NULL | NULL           | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                          | NULL |     NULL | No tables used                               |
+----+-------------+---------------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Whereas here is the `EXPLAIN` on a non 5.7 version:

```
mysql> explain update tkmemberstage join (select tkmemberstage.ID,(@newSequence := @newSequence+10) as newSequence from tkmemberstage cross join (select @newSequence := 0) constructedTable where tkmemberstage.tkmembershipID = 1  order by tkmemberstage.sequence) constructedTableReordered on tkmemberstage.ID=constructedTableReordered.ID set tkmemberstage.sequence=constructedTableReordered.newSequence;  
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref                          | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>    | ALL    | NULL           | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                         |    2 | NULL           |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | tkmemberstage | eq_ref | PRIMARY        | PRIMARY        | 8       | constructedTableReordered.ID |    1 | NULL           |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3>    | system | NULL           | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                         |    1 | Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tkmemberstage | ref    | tkmembershipID | tkmembershipID | 8       | const                        |    1 | Using where    |
|  3 | DERIVED     | NULL          | NULL   | NULL           | NULL           | NULL    | NULL                         | NULL | No tables used |
+----+-------------+---------------+--------+----------------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: I haven't checked, but while it certanly can be related to a versiln change, your update doesn't seem determunistic- could you add an order by to the update to discard that? Sometimes optimizer optimizations (or regressions) reveals bugs on the logic of a query- and yours look like one that would depend on the output order- which is not guarantee without an order by.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I do have `order by tkmemberstage.sequence` -- where else should an order by be inserted?

Comment: Discussion **[moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84835/discussion-between-ypercube-and-techmag)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely caused by one of these - or both:

- Lack of matching index for the query - on `(tkmembershipID, sequence)`. Without this index (and any index), the optimizer will likely choose a table scan.
- Optimization improvements on version 5.7. I've seen similar issues in other flavours (call me Maria) where an optimization improvement caused a query to use a different plan. Specifically, (after either version 5.3 or 5.5) MariaDB's optimizer knew that `ORDER BY` in subqueries is redundant, so it could be "optimized away".

  If a similar thing happens here, and the plan used gets rid of the `ORDER BY`, that explains the results.

  (And that may be considered a bug - as it changes your expected outcome when using variables. You can file a bug report to MySQL, with your situation and they may be able to fix it - or suggest a different solution/workaround).

In the mean time, I suggest you add the index mentioned above and check the plans again.

---

By the way, it seems like your query can be simplified to:

```
set @newSequence = 0 ; 

update tkmemberstage 
set sequence = (@newSequence := @newSequence + 10) 
where tkmembershipID = 1 
order by sequence ;
```

Comment: @Techmag To expand my initial suggestion- See that ORDER BY in the last update (it may not be sql-standard)?, that is the one I was mentioning it. An index may create an implicit order, but without the order by, it is still non deterministic. You should do all updates/deletes that affect multiple columns depending on the order with an explicit ORDER BY (e.g. another typical example would be `DELETE FROM ... LIMIT 10`). I personally would consider this not a server regression itself, but I can see it as annoying. The order by on subqueries should not affect the outer update-theoretically.

Comment: @jynus No, that is not standard. They could not add an `ORDER BY` in their UPDATE, MySQL does not allow it when the UPDATE has a join. It's only allowed for single table updates.

Comment: As I use a connection poo l is there any way not to do the "fix" (which works beautifully btw so thank you) as a single transaction? I use Scala (which uses most of Java's underlying mechanisms) and can wrap the transaction in a synchronoous block which would help but I've even seen those break under heavy load conditions. What will happen is one thread/connection will get the first statement and another thread/connection will get the second and this would of course break as `@newSequence` is not initialized. (Hmmm I should test that supposition first howedver).